# Sorting an array by two values

Tags: ruby

Suppose I have

```
an_array = [[2, 3], [1, 4], [1, 3], [2, 1], [1, 2]]
```

I want to sort this array by the first value of each inner array, and then by the second (so the sorted array should look like this: `[[1, 2], [1, 3], [1, 4], [2, 1], [2, 3]]`)

What's the most readable way to do this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is the default behavior for sorting arrays (see the [Array#<=>](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Array.html#M002204) method definition for proof). You should just be able to do:

```
 an_array.sort
```

Answer (score 9):

If you want some non-default behaviour, investigate `sort_by` (ruby 1.8.7+)

e.g. sort by the second element then by the first

```
a.sort_by {|e| [e[1], e[0]]}  # => [[2, 1], [1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 4]]
```

or sort by the first element ascending and then the second element descending

```
a.sort_by {|e| [e[0], -e[1]]}  # => [[1, 4], [1, 3], [1, 2], [2, 3], [2, 1]]
```

Answer (score 1):

`an_array.sort`